# Laravel Excel Maatwebsite/Excel showing +12

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Hmm you know guys why is this have a +12 ? Not showing a full text this is just a string in my PHP code. thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: That's how large numbers are represented in Mathematics, and in your case, Excel. If you want that to be a string, you'll need to format the column type to text: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html. Sidenote, if you include the code you're using to generate this Excel, it'll help us help you.

Comment: @TimLewis nice got it, thanks bro

Comment: Sweet! Feel free to post a self-answer to properly close this question. Cheers!

Comment: answered it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my answer here, just use DataType::TYPE_STRING, this now showing the data that I need.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;


$sheet->getCell("Y")->setValue($data["ref_num"])->setDataType(DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

[image]

Comment: Added this `$sheet->getCell('y')->setDataType('string');` but I got Invalid cell coordinate "Y"  PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Exception